# How to join on two columns using hibernate JPA annotations

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following  three relationships

The User table

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @SortNatural
    SortedSet<Project> projects;

    @OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    Company company;
```

The Project:

```
@ManyToOne
    User user;
    String company_name;
```

The Company:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "company")
    User user;
    String name;
```

This gives me a user_id in the Projects table But I also want the company name , a cloumn from the company table to be in the projects table? How do I join user table and projects table on two columns ( user_id and company_id) I want the company_name to be the name column from the Company table

Comment: if you want some name to be in the Projects table then you have to add a field there or a relation, so add it perhaps then the question would be more complete ...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Neil. Just added the column name

Comment: It is not clear what is the relationship between user and company. If it is OneToOne, change the company's user field annotation to OneToOne and define which side is owner of the relationship using the mappedBy property. If this is what you want, then you will be able get the name of the company from user.

Comment: Hi Fernado, I changed the question with your suggestion. How do I get Company.name field in the Project table? I am looking for the JPA annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you are using a model like this:

1. One **user** has zero or one **company**;
2. One **user** has zero, one or more **projects**;
3. The **project** table holds a foreign key (user_id) to **user**;
4. The **company** table holds a foreign key (user_id) to **user**.

I think you can define the following JPA mappings:

```
//User table
@Id
Long id; 
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@SortNatural
SortedSet<Project> projects;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
Company company;

//Project table
@Id
Long id;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
User user;

//Company table
@Id
Long id;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
User user;
String name;
```

This way after retrieving a project `p` you can get the company's name:

```
Project p = ... // code to select a project
String companyName = p.getUser().getCompany.getName();
```

Comment: How would I return the name of the company as a JsonProperty in the Projects class/